# In a ContentByQueryWebPart, how to generate a link to the item's display form?

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I'm building a custom Xsl to customize the rendering of a ContentByQueryWebPart. This webpart is targeting pictures

In the results, I would like to generate a link to the corresponding `dispform.aspx`, in order to show the details of the target picture.

How can I generate such link ?

By now, I have created this piece of Xsl to generate the link in my custom `ItemStyle.xsl` :

```
<xsl:variable name="DispFormUrl">
    <xsl:value-of
        disable-output-escaping="yes" 
        select="concat($SiteUrl, '/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId={',@ListId, '}&amp;ID=', @ID)" 
    />
</xsl:variable>
```

This is working when I work at the root of the site collection. However, this does not works if the results are from another web within the site collection.

How can I correct my xsl to support any location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up by creating my Xslt extension functions.

I followed [this blog post](http://www.helpmeonsharepoint.com/2012/05/create-your-own-xslt-functions-using-c.html) to create my custom function :

```
/// <summary>
/// Extend the Xslt transformation by adding new functions
/// </summary>
internal class ContentByQueryWebPartExXsltFunctions
{
    private static readonly Func<KeyValuePair<Guid, Guid>, string> displayFormGetter = FuncExtensions.Memoize(new Func<KeyValuePair<Guid, Guid>, string>((kp) =>
    {
        var site = SPContext.Current.Site;
        using (var web = site.OpenWeb(kp.Key))
        {
            var list = web.Lists[kp.Value];
            return list.DefaultDisplayFormUrl;
        }
    }));

    public string GetDisplayUrl(string webId, string listId, int itemId)
    {
        var webIdGuid = new Guid(webId);
        var listIdGuid = new Guid(listId);
        return displayFormGetter(new KeyValuePair<Guid, Guid>(webIdGuid, listIdGuid)) + "?ID=" + itemId;
    }
}

internal static class FuncExtensions
{
    public static Func<A, R> Memoize<A, R>(this Func<A, R> f)
    {
        var map = new Dictionary<A, R>();
        return a =>
        {
            R value;
            if (map.TryGetValue(a, out value))
                return value;
            value = f(a);
            map.Add(a, value);
            return value;
        };
    }
}
```

I use Memoization to reduce the opening of multiple SPWeb objects.

Then, I inherited the ContentByQueryWebEx to exploit this functions :

```
public class ContentByQueryWebPartEx : ContentByQueryWebPart
{
    protected override void ModifyXsltArgumentList(ArgumentClassWrapper argList)
    {
        var functions = new ContentByQueryWebPartExXsltFunctions();

        argList.AddExtensionObject("urn:ContentByQueryWebPartEx", functions);

        base.ModifyXsltArgumentList(argList);
    }

},
```

Finally, I update my ItemStyle.xsl to register and use this new function :

```
<xsl:stylesheet
      version="1.0"
      exclude-result-prefixes="x d xsl msxsl cmswrt"
      xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp"
      xmlns:cmswrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v3/Publishing/runtime"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
      xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"

      xmlns:cust="urn:ContentByQueryWebPartEx"
    >
    <xsl:template name="MyStyle"
                mode="itemstyle"
                match="Row[@Style='MyStyle']">   

        <xsl:variable name="DispFormUrl">
            <xsl:value-of select="cust:GetDisplayUrl(@WebId,@ListId,@ID)" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <a href="{$DispFormUrl}">Details</a>    

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Steve! I'm glad you used my blog post as a reference and very nice of you to put the link to it. Thanks again and good work!

Answer (score 1):

In order to provide the link to the picture item instead of picture url, 
I recommend to modify `SafeLinkUrl` variable in `ItemStyle.xsl` that is used for Item Url:

```
 <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
            <!--xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
                <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
            </xsl:call-template-->
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($RootSiteRef,'/_layouts/CopyUtil.aspx?Use=id&amp;Action=dispform&amp;ItemId=',@ID,'&amp;ListId=',@ListId,'&amp;WebId=',@WebId,'&amp;SiteId=',$SiteId,'&amp;Source=',$Source)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
```

### CopyUtil.aspx page

CopyUtil.aspx page is an application redirect page intended for redirection to the corresponding item or document.

The following parameters could be passed via URL:

- Item ID
- List ID
- Web ID
- Site ID
- Source
- List item
- Action
- InThisWeb